# Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed inside block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

[Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) say I can avoid a strong reference cycle by capturing a weak reference to self, like this:

```
- (void)configureBlock {
    XYZBlockKeeper * __weak weakSelf = self;
    self.block = ^{
        [weakSelf doSomething];   // capture the weak reference
                                  // to avoid the reference cycle
    }
}
```

Yet when I write this code, the compiler tells me:

> Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed due to possible null
>   value caused by race condition, assign it to strong variable first

Yet doesn't the following code create a strong reference cycle, and possibly leak memory?

```
- (void)configureBlock {
    XYZBlockKeeper *strongSelf = self;
    self.block = ^{
        [strongSelf doSomething];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `__weak XYZBlockKeeper *weakSelf` instead.  I am uncomfortable seeing the `__weak` on the right-hand side of the `*` (this might not make a difference, but try it out.  If it does then I have a theory why).

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I can't get this message to come out either way.  It is saying that you are doing something like `weakSelf->memberVariable = 123;`

Comment: @borrden You get this warning if you set the `-Wreceiver-is-weak` flag (available as the “Sending messages to __weak pointers” build setting).  Also, it's more sensible to put `__weak` after the star, because `__weak` applies to `weakSelf` (in that `weakSelf` will be set to zero, while `*weakSelf` will not be set to zero).  Consider that `typedef XYZBlockKeeper *XYZBlockKeeperRef; XYZBlockKeeperRef __weak weakSelf;` declares a weak reference, but `typedef __weak XYZBlockKeeper WeakXYZBlockKeeper; WeakXYZBlockKeeper *weakSelf;` does not (and gets a warning that `__weak` doesn't apply).

Comment: @borrrden: the `__weak` on the right hand of the `*` is *the correct* way to write it. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW7 Putting it anywhere else is wrong but tolerated.

Comment: @newacct Oh dear, shame on me >_<

Answer (score 28):

You should use like this one:
eg:

```
__weak XYZBlockKeeper *weakSelf = self;

self.block = ^{

    XYZBlockKeeper *strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf doSomething];
    } else {
        // Bummer.  <self> dealloc before we could run this code.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not required that you check `strongSelf` in this particular example.  You're allowed to send messages to `nil`; nothing happens.

Comment: But what's the difference (besides silencing the warning)?

Comment: The `strongSelf` is not weak by type, but is actually 'pointing' to a weak pointer. For the compiler, it 'looks like' a strong pointer (although, ref count does not change). Of course, once the `weakSelf` is released, so do the `strongSelf`. Simply put, the `strongSelf` is a strong pointer, that does not raise the ref count.

Comment: @bauerMusic are you sure? It if didn't bump the retain count, how would it maintain a strong reference? Thanks!

Comment: @DanRosenstark I wrote that the `strongSelf` does not raise the ref count. It's wrong. What I think I meant, it that when the block is copied, the retain count does not change, only when the block is called. You are correct, when the code in the block is running, the  `strongSelf` will bump the ref count.

Comment: Thanks for that, agreed. What I'm really interested in is whether `[weakSelf doSomething]` bumps the retain count (retaining weakSelf for the duration of the method call), or whether weakSelf can get deallocated while doSomething is running.